# Using tokens in web service

Tags: web-services, authentication

I'm building an app that needs to consume web services; i would like to implement a token-based authentication as follows:

- Username/Password are sent to the WS
- If validated, the server sends back a unique token to the client
- The client sends the token in all the following call to the WS and the token expiration time is updated to x minutes after this call.

If i send the username(or userid) in every WS call with the token have i done an acceptable WS architecture or should i do something more to improve security in my app?

Comment: What platform? Java? .NET? Language? Version?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication mechanism you described sounds a lot like the ones specified by the [WS-Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Trust) and [WS-SecureConversation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-SecureConversation) security standards.
Instead of reimplementing an authentication scheme from scratch, I would recommend you to rely on a library/framework that supports the WS-* security standards.